# Will Apple Reject my App on code sign identity selection?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have developed ios app

Now, i have submitted app to app store for approval,

In my **Xcode - organizer** archive vaidation and distribution is done successfully.

But in my Xcode **Project - Target - Code signing identity** section
i have selected  `iPhone Developer...` and selected same option for debug and release under code signing identity (See snapshot for more details..)

is it necessary to select **iPhone Distribution:compnyname...** in **Project - Target - Code signing identity** section ??

`Will Apple Reject my App ??`

[image]:

Comment: I think someone down-voted you because we can't really answer this question (it's Apple's decision), and perhaps it is a bit off-topic because it's not really a question about programming/software development

Comment: It's ontopic in my opinion and definitely answerable

Comment: The app you send to Apple must be signed with a store distribution provisioning profile. You can't use a development provisioning profile.

Comment: @rmaddy: app will be rejected ?

Comment: @Krunal You can't even submit the app unless it is properly signed with the proper provisioning profile.

Comment: I doubt you can even upload the App with a wrong provisoning profile. So yes.

Comment: i already submitted app and my app status shows: **Waiting for review**

Comment: @Krunal What's the point of this question anyway? Why wouldn't you simply follow the proper steps? Why are you trying to use a development profile for distribution?

Comment: write now i am in different country for few days and my laptop is at my house i wil reach my house after 4 days that's why i am confirming here else i would have done changes..

Comment: @Hless: app will be rejected ?

Comment: No, it won't be rejected. As simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be very surprised if Apple doesnt reject it, in fact their systems should have rejected it and not even allowed it to upload with a developer profile. A distribution profile is required for App Store distribtution. You should probably contact them for details.

Comment: as you can see in my post image, there are two distribution profile appears in dropdown. which one should i select ?

Comment: One is showing Test and the other is showing AppStore.. I assume you need the AppStore one.

Comment: Its also possible that the Binary that they got was already pre-signed with the correct one.

Comment: so,app will be rejected ?

Comment: I am saying that XCode may have already tried to use the Distribution Profile being that you were creating an IPA and you may have just gotten lucky. Your guess is as good as ours so just wait and see what happens.

Comment: Thanx.. for supporting bro, apple approved my app :) XCode  automatically selected the Distribution Profile.